# UnicodeDecodeError in Google app Engine python

Tags: python, google-app-engine, xlwt

I am writing excel file in google app engine , I am getting following error , whats wrong with the code ?

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xd0 in position 706: invalid continuation byte
```

Here is the code ,

```
myworkbook = xlwt.Workbook()
ws = myworkbook.add_sheet('Sheet1')
ws.write(0, 0, 'Cell of my sheet') 
myworkbook.save(self.response.out)
self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/excel'
self.response.out.write(self.response.out)
```

Comment: Why are you writing `self.response.out` back to `self.response.out`? You already wrote out `myworkbook` to the response stream..

Comment: I saved output of exel file to `self.response.out` , then writing `self.response.out` to output.Thats why.

Comment: And you don't see what the problem with that is?

Comment: sorry , please elaborate it.

Comment: `myworkbook.save(self.response.out)` *already calls `self.response.out.write`*. `self.response.out` is a file object. Writing it to `self.response.out` *again* makes no sense.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thank you very much , i got confused .

Comment: does that solve the problem though?

Comment: @MartijnPieters you need to answer (pity there isn't a way to move a comment to answer and vice versa)

Comment: @peterretief: When I am not certain about a code-base I usually resort to comments. I don't *have* to create an answer, of course; in this case, because my intuition was correct and problem was solved, it does make sense to do so. :-)

Comment: @Nishant so i guess you make it answered now?

Comment: @peterretief answer is already posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the following line:

```
self.response.out.write(self.response.out)
```

`myworkbook.save(self.response.out)` *already calls `self.response.out.write`*. `self.response.out` is a file object; writing that to `self.response.out` again makes no sense.